# Modifying MailItem.Body for VSTO Outlook Add-in?

Tags: c#, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2013, visual-studio-2015

We have been stuck on trying to edit the html body of email's for replys and fowards. We have a custom form that we want to append the header to the html email body depending on if its a new email reply or foward. How do you get the new body to override the reply and fowarded email body. The subject works just fine.

```
namespace OutlookAddIn
{
    public partial class ThisAddIn
    {
        private Outlook.Inspectors inspectors;

        private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            inspectors = this.Application.Inspectors;
            inspectors.NewInspector += new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.InspectorsEvents_NewInspectorEventHandler(Inspectors_NewInspector);
        }

        private void ThisAddIn_Shutdown(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            // Note: Outlook no longer raises this event. If you have code that 
            //    must run when Outlook shuts down, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=506785
        }

        void Inspectors_NewInspector(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Inspector Inspector)
        {
            Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Inspector.CurrentItem as Outlook.MailItem;
            if (mailItem != null)
            {
                if (mailItem.EntryID == null)
                {
                    ClassificationForm formMain = new ClassificationForm();
                    formMain.ShowDialog();
                    mailItem.HTMLBody = formMain.GetHTMLBody();
                    mailItem.Subject = formMain.GetSubject();
                }
            }
        }

        #region VSTO generated code

        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Startup += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Startup);
            this.Shutdown += new System.EventHandler(ThisAddIn_Shutdown);
        }

        #endregion
    }
}
```

Also tried this, which does replace the html email of the body but it does open two version of the emails, and ForwardingMessage.Display(true); does not fully work at displaying only the edited version of the email.

```
Outlook.MailItem ForwardingMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);
Outlook.MailItem SelectedMessage = (Outlook.MailItem)this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection[1];
if (SelectedMessage != null)
{
    if (ForwardingMessage != null)
    {
        ClassificationForm formMain = new ClassificationForm();
        formMain.ShowDialog();
        SelectedMessage.HTMLBody = formMain.GetHTMLBody();
        SelectedMessage.Subject = formMain.GetSubject();
     }
}
```

Comment: Sometimes you need to re-open the Outlook item if you need to get changes visible. Does it help?

Answer (score 0):

We solved it by doing a work around with adding a form region to the email that modifies the data and using a simply onsent event to append the data from the form region to the actual email.